# Write CSV with text in quotes, but numerical values without quotes

Tags: java, csv, export-to-csv, opencsv

Using OpenCSV, I'm trying to write a CSV file in which

- Text values are surrounded by `"` quotes.
- Numerical values are *not* surrounded by quotes (because they should be treated as numbers, not as strings, by the program that will eventually read the CSV file).

**Example desired output:**

Format required by the program that will read the CSV file:

```
"Header 1","Header 2","Header 3"
123.4,234.6,999.8
456456.32,1222.4,2222.2
```

**Attempted solution:**

My best attempt so far is:

```java
CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csvFile),',','\0');
```

where the quote char is set to `'\0'` i.e. the empty char (and the delimiter is left to be `,` as usual).

This puts no quotes around any values. To make up for the lack of `"` quotes around the text values, I "manually" prepend and append a litteral quote `"\""` to each text value (this is quite manageable, because my headers are really only the only things that have text in them).

```java
    for (int i=0;i<headers.length;++i) {
        headers[i] = "\"" + headers[i] + "\"";
    }
```

**Actual output:**

I really thought this would nail it, but the output looks like this:

```
""Header 1"",""Header 2"",""Header 3""
123.4,234.6,999.8
456456.32,1222.4,2222.2
```

Text values are enclosed in double quotes `""`!

- Why?
- How do I fix this?

Comment: I don't quite get you. The CSV spec states that data that contains a delimiter may _either_ have that delimiter escaped _or_ have that data quoted. There is no requirement to quote _all_ data that _may_ contain quotes. As this is not part of the CSV spec, OpenCSV cannot deal with it. You are looking for something more akin to a JSON array.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Are you referring to [RFC 4180](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) when you say "the spec"? If so, bear in mind the OpenCSV website [makes no reference to that RFC](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=4180+site%3Aopencsv.sourceforge.net). So while I think your comments are probably sound, I'd be cautious about promoting the idea that there's a single spec somewhere that most implementations adhere to.

Comment: @Duncan, yes - I was. I just assumed that OpenCSV followed it. Yes, I know what happens [when you assume](http://xkcd.com/1339/).

Comment: @Jean Is it just the header that will contain text?

Comment: @Duncan: yes, just the headers for now. And your previous comment is right on as well.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett Good spot (on the duplicate) :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could specify the escape character to be `'\0'`, which would stop OpenCSV from escaping your existing quotes:

```
CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out),
        ',', '\0', '\0');
csvWriter.writeNext(new String[] { "\"Header 1\"", "\"Header 2\"",
        "\"Header 3\"" });
csvWriter.writeNext(new String[] { "123.4", "234.6", "999.8" });
csvWriter.close();
```

Output:

```
"Header 1","Header 2","Header 3"
123.4,234.6,999.8
```

Of course, you are swiftly reaching the stage where OpenCSV is doing nothing for you. If you handle all escaping and all quoting, then OpenCSV is just joining string arrays with commas.

It may be sensible to abandon the library and just write that small amount of code yourself - it will avoid confusion for future maintainers who think "*Hmmm, this is mighty odd CSV data we're producing here!*".

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the CSV spec (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) states that double quotes in values are escaped by doubling them, hence I assume that if you provide double quotes yourself, they are escaped and that *only if a value contains the delimiter* OpenCSV encloses it in double quotes.

Examples (delimiter is the comma):

```
Input           CSV
--------------------------------
test text    -> test
test, text   -> "test, text"     (double quotes because of the delimiter in the input)
"test text"  -> ""test text""    (double quotes are escaped)
"test, text" -> """test, text""" (double quotes because of delimiter, as well as escaped quotes)
```

Comment: In my question, I went out of my way to specify the desired output format, because that is the only format which I am guaranteed the next program in the chain will be able to read.

Comment: @Duncan: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180